# How to Save PDF file to disk or Open in Firefox using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: pdf, selenium, save

I am trying to save pdf file to disk or open pdf in different tab in firefox browser. This is what I have tried but I am unable to save file to desk. And I am also not sure how to find url of the pdf.

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", "C:\\Work");
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf,application/octet-stream, application/vnd.fdf, application/x-msdos-program, application/x-unknown-application-octet-stream, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-publisher, application/x-unknown-message-rfc822, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, application/x-mspublisher, application/x-tar, application/zip, application/x-gzip,application/x-stuffit,application/vnd.ms-works, application/powerpoint, application/rtf, application/postscript, application/x-gtar, video/quicktime, video/x-msvideo, video/mpeg, audio/x-wav, audio/x-midi, audio/x-aiff");
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

        //Use this to disable Acrobat plugin for previewing PDFs in Firefox (if you have Adobe reader installed on your computer)
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "99.0");
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("plugin.scan.plid.all", false);
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325249/save-as-pdf-chrome-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="path/to/geckodriver.exe")


----------

Set preferences for automatic PDF download. You can do this by setting the preference as True

    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
    firefox_profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="path/to/geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
    driver.get("https://example.com/path/to/your/file.pdf")

To find the url to the pdf, you can search for a href tag which has the extension. 

    pdf using xpath "//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]"
    
    pdf_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]")
    pdf_url = pdf_link.get_attribute("href")
    driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{pdf_url}', '_blank');")
    driver.close()


----------


Switch to the new tab where the PDF was opened and interact with the browser's download dialog to save the file

    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```