# Save As PDF Chrome using selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am looking to automate "Save as PDF" of Chrome using selenium. AFAIK it is not supported by the Selenium out of the box. Therefore, i am trying to write my own. I am having an issue. Actually clicking on the Print button in my webpage opens a new window with printable area. I am trying to switch to this window using SwitchTo. But it is timing out always.

Comment: you need to use AutoIT bec. it's windows instance can't handle by selenium ref this https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html

Comment: But i am getting the handle in the  ` driver.WindowHandles ` only i am unable to switch.

Comment: you are doing using CLT+P ?

Comment: no there is a button in the webpage. it basically opens a window in the browser. I am trying to get the newly opened window.

Comment: Can you please share your link or screenshot.. It would be more clear

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't. A button in webpage opens another webpage with the printable area. This new webpage does not have anything in the address bar. I need to switch to this page which is not happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150183/discussion-between-user2580925-and-ankur-singh).

Answer (score 2):

You can add the options.AddArgument("--kiosk-printing"); to have it automatically click the print button.

That is working for me but I have a problem setting the printer to Save as PDF. It is printing to the printer instead.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I still get the print preview page. Using Chrome 81

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable the Chrome PDF plugin and download promt window with desired capabilities. Something like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability("download.default_directory","C:");
cap.setCapability("download.prompt_for_download","false");
cap.setCapability("directory_upgrade","true");
cap.setCapability("plugins.plugins_disabled","Chrome PDF Viewer");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: Actually the issue with the Window handle. I had a look at the javascript. On clicking on the Button it is opening another window using Window.Open. Now selenium is unable to switch to this window. Though it is getting the handle by driver.WindowHandles.

Comment: `for( String e : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            System.out.println("Window handle: " + e)};` What it will return? And You are unable to perform: `driver.switchTo().window("Number of window handle as string")`?

Comment: Yes i am getting the Window handle string. `driver.switchTo().window("Number of window handle as string") ` hangs the execution and throws timeout error.